# Get checkbox insert input value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have checkbox function that can only select one value. If user choose option of `other` they have to insert the value.

[image]

And now I'm trying to get the value of the inserted input by the user.
[image]

But I got this in my `console.log` it's not displaying any value that I have inserted before.
[image]

How do I fix the jQuery in order to get the input value if user choose `others` as the option ?

```js
let subject_type = '';

$('input[name="web[]"]').change(function() {
  $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  if (this.value != 'others') {
    subject_type = this.value;
  } else if (this.value == 'others') {

    subject_type = $("#subject_name").val();
 
  }
});

$("#subject").hide();
$("#oth_subject").change(function() {
  if ($("#oth_subject").is(':checked')) {
    $("#subject").show();
  } else {
    $("#subject").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30">
  <label>Pick A Subject</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" value="Science"> Science</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" value="Math"> Math</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" id="oth_subject" value="others">Others</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 mb-30" id="subject" class="row">
  <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Insert the subject you wish </b></label><br>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="subject_name">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm checking the value in the `formData` entries.

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
<button type="button" sendForm ="submit()">SEND</button>
</div>

const sendForm = () =>{
 let formData  = new FormData();
//assuming I have another data just u show this
 formData.append('subject', subject_type);
           
 for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
       console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
   }
}
}
```

Comment: _"it's not displaying any value that I have inserted before."_ - and by "before", you actually mean _before_ you clicked the "Others" checkbox? Because on the first time you are trying to read this field value, the user did not have a chance to add any yet ...

Comment: And why are you misusing checkboxes to do what _radio buttons_ were explicitly made for?

Comment: @CBroe no I what i meant is I have clicked the `others` option and inserted the value in the input. when I tried to submit the form I checking the value and it did not show any value that has been inserted in the input

Comment: @CBroe I know there is the radio but I for some reason if I have to use checkbox style.

Comment: Use a radio group and *style* it which ticks/checks.  Save you many a headache.

Comment: I ran your code I click on `Others` checkbox and then I start to type some text in `subject_name` textbox after that I can get the value of text box by `$("#subject_name").val();` in console. So what is the problem?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi i'm not getting the value. i will try again

Comment: You're not getting the value because you're checking it too soon

Comment: Ok show how you are getting the value. I mean your submit button

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi updated. that's how i check the value in console log

Comment: Instead of `subject_type` use `$("#subject_name").val();` and you don't need any `change` event for textbox

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi in the formData ?

Comment: Everywhere you need the value of `textbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for a change in the other `subject` input:

```js
let subject_type = '';

$('input[name="web[]"]').change(function() {
  $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  if (this.value != 'others') {
    subject_type = this.value;
  } else if (this.value == 'others') {

    subject_type = $("#subject_name").val();
  }
});

$("#subject").hide();
$("#oth_subject").change(function() {
  if ($("#oth_subject").is(':checked')) {
    $("#subject").show();
  } else {
    $("#subject").hide();
  }
});

$('#subject').change(function() {
  subject_type = $("#subject_name").val();
  console.log(subject_type)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30">
  <label>Pick A Subject</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" value="Science"> Science</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" value="Math"> Math</label></li>
      <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" id="oth_subject" value="others">Others</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 mb-30" id="subject" class="row">
  <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Insert the subject you wish </b></label><br>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="subject_name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mailme you simply do this by use change event on subject input:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30">
    <label>Pick A Subject</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <ul>
                <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" value="Science"> Science</label></li>
                <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" value="Math"> Math</label></li>
                <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" id="oth_subject" value="others">Others</label></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 mb-30" id="subject" class="row">
    <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Insert the subject you wish </b></label><br>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <input class="from-control" type="text" id="subject_name">
        </div>
</div>

    let subject_type = '';

 $('input[name="web[]"]').change(function() {
    
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    if (this.value != 'others'){
        subject_type = this.value;
    }
    else if (this.value == 'others'){
                
        subject_type = $("#subject_name").val();

    }
});

$("#subject").hide();

$("#oth_subject, #subject").change(function(){
    
    if ($("#oth_subject").is(':checked')){
        $("#subject").show();
    }else{
        $("#subject").hide();
    }

    subject_type = $("#subject_name").val();
    if(subject_type)
        console.log(subject_type);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any `change` event just use `("#subject_name").val()` everywhere you need the value of `subject_name` the text box:

```js
$("#subject").hide();
$("#oth_subject").change(function () {
    if ($("#oth_subject").is(':checked')) {
        $("#subject").show();
    } else {
        $("#subject").hide();
    }
});

const sendForm = () => {
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('subject', $("#subject_name").val());

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-30">
        <label>Pick A Subject</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <ul>
                <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" value="Science"> Science</label></li>
                <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" value="Math"> Math</label></li>
                <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="web[]" id="oth_subject" value="others">Others</label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-30" id="subject" class="row">
        <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Insert the subject you wish </b></label><br>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <input class="from-control" type="text" id="subject_name">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button type="button" onclick="sendForm()">SEND</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: that will be another case if user choose math/science then I wont be able to get the value of math/science

Comment: @mailme this gives you the same result with above answers but without any `change` event!!

Comment: i understand it nowwww. thank youuu for another knowledge

Comment: @mailme I am glad it helped. let me know if there is a problem bro

Comment: no no everything is good! i didnt realize it. upvote it back. im sorry.